# How to Concatenate a PHP variable and a string

Tags: php, wordpress

might be a very dumb question but i'm trying to make a html string with a php var and then html..  what the heck am I doing wrong?!? :(

```
$author_name = get_the_author(); ?>
<h4><?php $author_name;?> On-Demand Webinars</h4>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you forgot the `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missed the `echo`.

```
<h4><?php echo $author_name;?> On-Demand Webinars</h4>
```

Comment: sometimes it's the simplest of things and an extra pair of eyes solves the problem!  Thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: Or simply `<?=$author_name;?>`

Answer (score 1):

You missed "echo" statement
e.g

```
 <?php echo $author_name;?> On-Demand Webinars

 OR

 <?=$author_name;?>
```